# Need to generate the assembly code for structures and variables

Tags: gcc, assembly, data-structures, disassembly

I need to understand some internals of data structures by generating the assembly code for functions and global, local structures, variables.

From this link:

```
http://axelio.wordpress.com/2007/07/24/be-careful-with-packed-structures/
```

I can see that the structure members are shown the allocated size explicitly in assembly code.

```
_my:
    .byte   10  <--- c
    .long   20  <--- i
    .byte   30  <--- s.c
    .space 3    <--- 3 bytes of alignment
    .long   40  <--- s.i
```

How to generate this kind of assembly. 
Using

```
# gcc -S  file.c
```

didnot generate the above output for structures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does.

```
struct S
{
  int x;
  float y;
};

struct S t = {
  .x = 10,
  .y = 1.0
};
```

Compile with `gcc -S strasm.c`

And in resulting `strasm.s` you will see:

```
  .data
  .type t, @object
  .size t, 8
t:
  .long 10
  .long 1065353216
```

All you need is explicitly initialized object.

Comment: Yes i didn't initialize the object.